# Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Prove that $\,x f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$.

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(0) = 0$. Prove that $\,x  f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$.

There is hint that says: just do the fraction out and use limit theorems (i.e. closed under addition, multiplication, etc.).

I'm not really sure what to do at all. Does it have something to do with product rule?

Comment: The hint is telling you to use the definition of derivative at $0$.

Comment: Well $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{hf(h) - 0}{h} = \lim f(h) = f(0) = 0$. So letting $g(x) = xf(x)$, we have $g'(0) = 0$.

Comment: The condition of continuity of $f(x)$ and $f(0) = 0$ is unnecessary. Only thing we need is the existence of $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Not quite right. You also need $f(0)$ to be defined.

Comment: For a func to be continuous / differentiable, definition at the point of consideration is a must. Only for limits we don't need the definition at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(x) = x\cdot f(x)$. By the definition of differentiability, we want the following limit to converge

$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{g(h) - g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{h\cdot f(h) - 0\cdot f(0)}{h}  = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{h\cdot f(h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} f(h) = 0
$$

Note the last step requires us to know $f$ is continuous (really we just need to know the limit exists, and continuity implies this).